# How do I pipe input to a command using powershell in a Dockerfile?

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to write a Dockerfile to build a windows image containing the android sdk.

During the installation of the sdk, the sdkmanager requires you to enter 'y' several times to accept licenses before continuing. I've been able to automate this in a normal powershell outside docker with the following line:

```
"y`n" * 8 | & '.\bin\sdkmanager.bat' --licenses
```

However, when I try to put this in the Dockerfile, it doesn't work. The sdkmanager ignores the input and just exits immediately at the first prompt.

Dockerfile (the triple quotes seem necessary to prevent them being stripped):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

RUN iwr -UseBasicParsing https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip -OutFile sdk-tools.zip
RUN Expand-Archive sdk-tools.zip 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk'
RUN """y`n""" * 8 | & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat' --licenses
RUN & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat' tools platform-tools
```

Output:

```
Step 7/14 : RUN iwr -UseBasicParsing https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip -OutFile sdk-tools.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfb0b47e99b8
Step 8/14 : RUN Expand-Archive sdk-tools.zip 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a87ab84f86d0
Step 9/14 : RUN """y`n""" | & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat' --licenses
 ---> Running in b5caf5584ba3
Warning: File C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
7 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?
Removing intermediate container b5caf5584ba3
 ---> 2d88d3c72d9a
Step 10/14 : RUN & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat' tools platform-tools
 ---> Running in 27e8f5e804e9
```

I assume this is maybe a docker build limitation where it doesn't wait for user input. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you really don't find a clean way, try this: remove everything in your dockerfile after step 8. Build your image then run this `docker run -it your-intermediate-image 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat'`you will be in your container in interactive mode. Answer yes as many times as needed and when you're done exit and commit you image. Then write a second docker file based on this image.

Comment: Have you tried saving it in a .ps1 file that you COPY in to the docker image, and then RUN that?